# Manifest invalid file after publishing extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

when developing locally my manifest.json works but when published to the extension store it just says 'invalid manifest'.

manifest.json:

```
{
"name": "my fancy name",
"version": "0.0.3",
"description": "my fancy desc",
"manifest_version": 2,
"permissions": ["activeTab", "tabs"],
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
},
"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["https://*.youtube.com/watch*"],
    "js": ["main.js"],
    "run_at": "document_idle",
    "css": ["styles.css"]
}],
"icons": {
    "16": "images/icon16.png",
    "32": "images/icon32.png",
    "48": "images/icon48.png",
    "128": "images/icon128.png"
}
```

}

Anyone?

Comment: Try looking for similar questions. Maybe your zip is nonstandard, try a different utility. Make sure your files are in the root of zip, not inside a wrapper directory (if this is not clear, post a link to your actual zip file here).

Answer (score 0):

It fixed by itself by chrome store.